# Run ParseLoginInBackground in background thread until ParseUser is not null?

Tags: android, parse-platform, handler, background-thread

My goal is to process user login in a background thread that does not lock the UI thread. It appears that `ParseUser.logInInBackground()` is a Task, which is an asynchronous operation, but from experience you will quickly see that it is always blocking.

[image]

```
ParseUser.logInInBackground(email, password) {
        user,
        e - >
        if (e == null && user != null) {
            onLoginSuccess()
            // progressBar.visibility = View.GONE
        } else {
            onLoginFailed()
        }
```

Are there any alternatives? Can we call `Parse.login()` in a clearly defined background thread and wait for the condition `ParseUser != null` before executing subsequent code?

Comment: Why do you say that ```ParseUser.logInInBackground()``` is blocking the ui? Do you have any code example showing that? It should work in background actually.

Comment: Sync operations blocks the UI. Async operations does not that's the why language developers created async operations.